# how can I use two 'ref' methods from firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am using react js + firebase's realtime database and storage. I want to store an image and text contents to storage and realtime database respectively.

```
import {getDatabase, ref, set} from "firebase/database";
import {getStorage, ref} from "firebase/storage";
```

There was an error. I cannot import two 'ref' methods in same page.

```
Identifier 'ref' has already been declared. (32:22)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
import {getDatabase, ref as ref_database, set} from "firebase/database";
import {getStorage, ref as ref_storage} from "firebase/storage";
```